# SQL Server: Result that matches all values in a list

Tags: sql

I have two tables which are listed below.

## TableA

```
StudentID   StudentName
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D
5           E
```

## TableB

```
StudentID  ClassID  SectionID
1          2        5
3          2        7
```

Now I am trying to retrieve those students for which all items in an input list matches.

For example, If I pass the input list (ClassID & SectionID) as (2, 5), it should return StudentID : 1

If I pass the input list as (2, 5 | 1, 1) it should not return the StudentID : 1

```
DECLARE @tblData AS TABLE
(
     [ClassID]      INT
    ,[SectionID]    INT

)

INSERT INTO @tblData VALUES (2, 5)
INSERT INTO @tblData VALUES (2, 1)

SELECT
     A.[StudentID]
    ,A.[StudentName]
    ,B.[ClassID]
    ,B.[SectionID]
FROM
    [AAAAAA] AS A
        INNER JOIN [BBBBBB] AS B
            ON A.[StudentID] = B.[StudentID]
        INNER JOIN @tblData AS C
            On B.[ClassID] = C.[ClassID] AND B.[SectionID] = C.[SectionID]
```

Unfortunately, the above mentioned query does not return the expected value.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should `JOIN` table `B` with `@tblData` and group by `StudentId`. Then using `HAVING` select all `StudentID` from this connection where count of rows = count of rows in `@tblData`. It means that this `studentId` matches ALL items in an input list

```
SELECT
     A.[StudentID]
    ,A.[StudentName]
    ,B.[ClassID]
    ,B.[SectionID]
FROM  A
     INNER JOIN B
            ON A.[StudentID] = B.[StudentID]
     INNER JOIN 
       (
          SELECT StudentID FROM @tblData
                           JOIN B ON  @tblData.ClassID=B.ClassID 
                                      AND 
                                      @tblData.SectionID=B.SectionID
          GROUP BY StudentID
          HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tblData)
) AS T1 on A.StudentID=T1.StudentID
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8564b/2)

Comment: Hi Valex, Thanks for your great help. But I have modified the records in the SQLFiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33551/1. Now it should return the StudentID 1 and 3. Can you please look into this?

Comment: Hi Valex, if I change this line HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @tblData) as HAVING COUNT(*) > 0, then it is working fine. Am I right? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that since you are Joining the @tblData with B, the engine matches the whole table B with @tblData. This way, if you pass a list of input values, you will get every student that matches with one entry in @tblData.

To avoid this, you could insert either some where/groupby clause that matches the count of entries for one student with the count of entries in @tblData or a subquery.

Comment: Hi Benedikt, Thanks for your reply. Can you please provide me an example of this?